# How can I force MySQL to IGNORE ALL indexes?

Tags: mysql, index, mysql-5.6

I have read articles about `FORCE` index, but how can I force MySQL to `IGNORE ALL` indexes?

I tried `SELECT * FROM tbl IGNORE INDEX(*)`, but I was not successful.

As for why I (and others) need to do this: For example, I needed to summarize referers statistics by tld like this:

```
SELECT 
    count(*) as c, 
    SUBSTRING
    (
        domain_name, 
        LENGTH(domain_name) - LOCATE('.', REVERSE(domain_name)) + 2
    ) as tld
FROM `domains_import` 
    IGNORE INDEX(domain_name)
GROUP BY tld
ORDER BY c desc
LIMIT 100
```

...but I always have to look at what indexes are defined or determine what index will be used via Explain. It would be very handy to simply write `IGNORE INDEX ALL` and simply not care.

Does anyone know the syntax or a hack? (Tens of lines via MySQL definition tables are really not a shortcut).

#### Added from [chat discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26874/discussion-between-mvorisek-and-ypercube):

Bechmark:

- no index = 148.5 secs
- with index = 180 secs and still running with Sending data
  The SSD array is so powerful, that you almost no care about data cache...

Definition for benchmark:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `domains_import` (
`domain_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
`domain_name` varchar(253) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `domains_import`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`domain_id`),
ADD UNIQUE KEY `domain_name` (`domain_name`);

ALTER TABLE `domains_import`
MODIFY `domain_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

InnoDB, the test with index (no USE INDEX() or similar) is still running, 250 secs, I just killed it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's absolutely not clear why you want this but you can use the hint `USE INDEX ()` to tell the optimizer not to use any index. From MySQL docs: [index hints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-hints.html)

> It is syntactically valid to **omit *`index_list`* for `USE INDEX`**, which **means “use no indexes.”** Omitting index_list for `FORCE INDEX` or `IGNORE INDEX` is a syntax error.

Your query becomes:

```
SELECT count(*) AS c, 
       substring_index(domain_name, '.', -1) AS tld
FROM domains_import 
       USE INDEX ()        -- use no indexes
GROUP BY tld
ORDER BY c DESC
LIMIT 100 ;
```

---

Side note: the complex expression:

```
SUBSTRING(domain_name, LENGTH(domain_name) - LOCATE('.', REVERSE(domain_name)) + 2)
```

can be simplified from 4 function calls to 1:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(domain_name, '.', -1)
```

Comment: It was useful for me when MySQL 5.7.10 optimizer changed its querying plan for a worst one when removing some of the `LEFT JOIN` I had. ` USE INDEX ()` made MySQL doing a table scan on a 20K rows table and 1-to-1 `JOIN`s instead of crossing 500 rows between two indexes. Got 20x faster.

Answer (score 2):

You could also embed `WHERE 1=1`

```
SELECT 
    count(*) as c, 
    SUBSTRING
    (
        domain_name, 
        LENGTH(domain_name) - LOCATE('.', REVERSE(domain_name)) + 2
    ) as tld
FROM `domains_import` 
WHERE 1=1
GROUP BY tld
ORDER BY c desc
LIMIT 100
```

ypercube just asked me

> Rolando, is MySQL's optimizer so dumb that a simple always true condition will forbid the use of indexes?

Yes, but you have give MySQL a really dumb query. `1=1` would revert to the Clustered Index. Notwithstanding, there is still another way, but it requires being a little malicious to the Optimizer.

```
SELECT 
    count(*) as c, 
    SUBSTRING
    (
        domain_name, 
        LENGTH(domain_name) - LOCATE('.', REVERSE(domain_name)) + 2
    ) as tld
FROM `domains_import` 
WHERE domain_name = domain_name
GROUP BY tld
ORDER BY c desc
LIMIT 100
```

This will throw every index under the bus for sure because each row's value for `domain_name` much be checked. If `domain_name` is indexed, you must choose a column for the `WHERE column_name=column_name` that is not indexed at all.

I just tried this on a large table in a Staging server

```
mysql > explain SELECT COUNT(1) FROM VIDEO WHERE EMBEDDED_FLG=EMBEDDED_FLG;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | VIDEO | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 354327 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

No indexes are chosen

Comment: Rolando, is MySQL's optimizer so dumb that a simple always true condition will forbid the use of indexes?

Comment: @ypercube yes, but you have to dummy-down the query enough for that to happen.

Comment: You can not beat @ypercube answer. Do you know any good source of using/not using indexes? I know relative much about indexes, but sometime I am facing with not using index because different collations etc.

Comment: Hey, I upvoted yercube's answer myself. My answer is just another way and explains the Optimizer's loophole.

Comment: Rolando, not true: The index will be used: [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a880b/11). Even if you make something more complicated, like `WHERE id+0 = id*1` the index will still be used, and an extra `Using where` will appear.

Comment: I also upvoted your answer, but will the loophole work also in MySQL 8.0? Are there any strict rules when the MySQL optimalizer will be excluded?

Comment: @yercube I just tried and no index is chosen, not even the Clustered Index (MySQL 5.6.21)

Comment: @PaulWhite it would. (it's dumb but not that dumb ;) And that's maybe why Roalndo's query does not use index, the column must have been defined as NULL.

Comment: Seems that it works even in case of NOT NULL column: `where mp = mp` shows as `where 1` in explain extended, but still no index is used (MariaDB 10.0)

Comment: @jkavalik Maybe indexes are not used but are you talking about but the same query and table? Or another example? Can you test my sqlfiddle (see comment above) in Maria 10.0?

Comment: @ypercube you use `where name = name` in that fiddle - but `name` is indexed. Rolando specifies that "If domain_name is indexed, you must choose a column for the WHERE column_name=column_name that is not indexed at all." and that was what I used. Can't test MariaDB just now but I previously tried similar to your fiddle and it too used the index to do the WHERE. There is the fiddle modified a bit to what I tried - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7177a/3

Comment: @jkavalik That explains things, thnx. (I used `name=name` because that's what Rolando's query has)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have these two indexes:

```
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`domain_id`),
ADD UNIQUE KEY `domain_name` (`domain_name`);
```

Then it does not matter what the optimizer does; it must scan essentially an identical amount of stuff.

Case 1:  It does a table scan (or uses domain_id):  It will scan (id, name) pairs, locating all the names, doing the SUBSTRING..LOCATE, GROUP BY, and finally ORDER BY.  The GROUP BY and the ORDER BY probably each need a tmp table and filesort.  Check `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to see if it does.

Case 2:  It does a index scan (of domain_name):  That index actually contains (name, id) pairs -- because InnoDB implicitly puts the PK on the end of any secondary key.  The rest of the processing parallels Case 1.

One thing *could* be different -- the size of the two BTrees.  Do `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE domains_import` to see the Data_length (for Case 1) and Index_length (for Case 2).  The larger BTree will be slower.

Another thing could be different -- caching.  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How much RAM do you have?  Can the Data (or Index) be contained within the buffer pool.  (Or will it be 37% of it, due to this being a table/index scan?)  If it fits, then run the query twice.  The *second* time will be about 10 times as fast due to not hitting the disk (caching).

If this is a one-time task, SSD will help.  If not, and you can cache the entire table, then it won't help after the buffer_pool is loaded.